# c# how to create loop until condition is met?

Tags: c#

Write a program that will continue to prompt the user to guess a number until the correct number has
been entered. You should also consider user validation; that is, has the user entered a number less than
1 or greater than 10? Have they entered a character? Start by creating a new project and name its main
class (and file) as GuessingNumber. Then proceed with the following steps:
 Create an integer variable called number and set it equal to 5.
 Prompt the user to guess a number between 1 and 10.
 If the user enters number 5, print “You have guessed the number! Well done!”
 If they do not enter 5, continue to prompt the user to enter a number until they enter 5.

Here is my code so far
using System;

namespace Progam

{

```
class Program

{

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 10");

        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (number < 1 || number > 10)

        {

            Console.WriteLine("This is out of the range");

        }

        if (number == 5)

        {

            Console.WriteLine("you have guessed the correct number");

        }

    }

}
```

}

How would I write the code to prompt the user to guess again if the number is not equal to 5?
Thanks

Comment: A [`do { ... } while ();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do) loop may help...

Comment: You shouldn't copy-paste the question from whatever place your are learning for us to do the work for you. If you had phrased your question better, people would be eager to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code slightly modified. There are many other ways to do this, this is one and a bit more readable for newer programmers.

```
    bool Correct = false;
    while (!Correct)
    {
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (number < 1 || number > 10)

        {

            Console.WriteLine("This is out of the range");

        }

        if (number == 5)

        {

            Console.WriteLine("you have guessed the correct number");
            Correct = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: This works.  Only thing I'd suggest is using `int.TryPasre` instead.  The requirements include handling invalid input that won't convert to `int`.  But an easy to understand loop.

Comment: Agreed. I was trying to keep his code as close to his original as possible.

Comment: I know.  That's why I upvoted.  Merely wanted to add it as a comment so OP can see in case he runs into issues parsing non integer stringers.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ok = false;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 10");

        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var number))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a number");
            continue;
        }

        if (1 > number || number > 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is out of the range");
            continue;
        }

        ok = number == 5;
        if (ok)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you have guessed the correct number");
        }
    } while (!ok);
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(1,10).Contains(number)` is overkill and O(N).

Comment: Ok. But common... it just 1 to 10 in your i7 )

Comment: My Ryzen, sure.  But bad performance simply because we can (and CPUs can handle it) is bad practice.  Especially when the O(1) solution is simple.

Comment: if serious you right. I fixed it

Comment: Yup, I'm [serious](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/09/06/the-premature-optimization-is-evil-myth/).  It's just good habit to write good code.  Someone will inevitably copy this code and make it `Enumerable.Range(1,10000).Contains(number)` not understanding the performance implications.

Comment: I agree completely.

Answer (score -2):

Sure hope I get a good grade!

```
do
{
   var number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   ....
}while(number != 5)
```

Comment: You're forgetting scope here.  This won't even compile.  So no dice on a good grade.

Comment: drats...now I'll never make it as a professional developer!